# Вывод записей из определенной рубрики WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Здравствуйте. На WordPress публикую записи, в созданную мной рубрику. Рубрике задал метку **news** , получается что все записи этой рубрики выводятся на странице *сайт/category/news/* . Но они выводятся так: Миниатюра, Заголовок, Дата, И ПОЛНЫЙ ТЕКСТ ЗАПИСИ.

Возможно ли сделать чтоб записи из этой рубрики выводились на странице *сайт/category/news/* без текста статьи? то есть так: Миниатюра, Заголовок, Дата.

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За вывод записей на страницах рубрик отвечает файл темы `category.php`, если такой отсутствует, то `archive.php`.
Найдите там участок кода (будет находиться внутри цикла `while(have_posts())`), со списком статей и удалите (закомментируйте) вызов функции `the_content();`, либо `echo get_the_content();`

Указанный файл находится в папке с активной темой. Путь к ней будет примерно таким: `wp-content/themes/имя_вашей_темы`